# working with repeated values in json array in node.js

Tags: jquery, json, node.js

Following is my Json data

```
myArray = [{  
    id: '71',
    mode: 'daily',
    os: 'VM-WIN7-64'},   
  {    
    id: '45',
    mode: 'daily',
    os: 'VM-WIN7-32'},
  { 
    id: '37',
    mode: 'daily',
    os: 'VM-WIN7-64',
    },
  { 
    id: '67',
    mode: 'daily',
    os: 'VM-WIN7-32-1',
    }  ];
```

Follwoing code is used to start a `Vmware` based on passing operating system and pass a `job id`(unique).

It is working properly for me.
My problem is in `myArray` contains repeated `os`(here starting same `os` repeatly but id's different-no need to start repeated `os`) at the same time i have to pass `id` assosiated with that in the below code.How it is possible?

```
myArray.forEach(function (job) {
    exec('/bin/Jobs.exe', ['MODE=Start', 'ID=' + job.os, 'JOBID=' + job.id], function (err, data) {
                            console.log(err);                   
                            console.log(data);
        });
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you need to filter out duplicates?

Comment: You want all ids for a particular OS ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use filter and keep track of duplicates inside a temporary array.

```
var unique = [];

myArray = myArray.filter(function(elem) {
  if(unique.indexOf(elem.os) < 0 ) {
    unique.push(elem.os)
    return true;
  }
  return false;
})
```